# Include print style sheet

Tags: css

How do I properly link a print style sheet? 
All my styles have been enqueued through functions file.

The codex suggested I put the link in the header but this didn't work, is there a core print stylesheet?

I tried to create a link in the header but I see any of these styles?
I do see the print.css file in the header when I look at the source.

/css/print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to add a print stylesheet, note the `media` parameter that lets you make it a print-specific stylesheet:

```
function wpa_print_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'wpa-print-style', 
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/print-style.css', 
        array(), 
        '20130821', 
        'print' // print styles only
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_print_styles' );
```